# Calculating code coverage using EMMA with Functional test Suite( for android app)

Tags: functional-programming, code-coverage, using, emma, suite

Our development team is using EMMA to calculate the code coverage using the JUnit Testcases for an Android Application.

I am a Tester who is testing android application through automation using SeeTest and Test Complete tools.**I want to calculate the code coverage by using EMMA by running the Functional Test Suite( which are in SeeTest and Test Complete).** Its frustrating to see that there is no documentation available for this. Anybody who has achieved this, please help me out on this.